# win32 Api programming

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to get a running application text e.g if i am running notepad then i want to get the text written inside it .For this first i have to get the handle of notepad but i don't know how to get the notepad handle so please tell me .Then through which functions i can get its inside text ? which header files to include ? what are necessary declarations?
Please help me i am new to windows API programming.i have gone through basic tutorials of windows programming but that doesn't help me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Use [FindWindowEx](http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/3243388/Re-FindWindowEx-handle-and-notepad-exe.aspx). Though you must have been able to find this yourself, if you were looking/googling for a way to "find notepad handle in C++" ;)

You can even find complete examples on "[Sending text to notepad in C++](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/code/259700)"

Comment: My basic problem is how to get notepad window handle and moreover i want to retrieve text from notepad

Comment: ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open", "mytext.txt", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);    Just for completeness, that example on daniweb needs to request the user opens notepad, this line may open it for you (I uses it for firefox and "stackoverflow.com/index.html" for example). The 'A' suffix is some strange (un)ASCI-ness on my system.

Comment: You get the notepad window handle using FindWindowEx, as demonstrated in the examples I linked to. The links being that blue text in my answer. You can actually click on them to get to a page with that information on it. :)

Comment: That said, there is hardly ever a practicle use to controlling Notepad in this way. It's way easier and more solid if you just put a text box on a form of your own. But that's an entirely different tutorial.

Comment: thnx everyone for help .@goleztrol i can't find link in your answer btwn i am now able to get the window handle.Now facing one problem i can't get the the text written inside any running application not necessary notepad that could be wordpad ,VS or any other application that has some text written inside it.Plz provide me the win32 appropriate function

Comment: It's not gonna work. Notepad is a simple text editor with just a window control to send messages to. Other applications work in different ways. There is not a generic way to copy text from other applications, except for using the clipboard. You could try to activate the other application and simulate a Ctrl+C keystroke using the `keybd_event` api. But it's getting very messy if you need to resort to that kind of a solution.

Comment: You can get a handle to the edit control but it won't help you much. The docs for GetWindowText() explicitly say the function will not retrieve text from an edit control of another application.

Comment: You can use the WM_GETTEXT message to get text from a control in another application. It's in the same docs. :)

Answer (score 1):

To expand on GolezTrol's answer, you could do this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int CALLBACK _tWinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow ) {
  HWND hwnd = FindWindow( _T("Notepad"), NULL);
  hwnd      = FindWindowEx( hwnd, NULL, _T("edit"), NULL );

  TCHAR lpText[256];
  SendMessage( hwnd, WM_GETTEXT, _countof(lpText), (LPARAM)lpText);
  MessageBox(0, lpText, lpText, 0);
  return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

In reality, you would probably use a more reliable method of window identification (eg. enumerating all windows and verifying what process it belongs to)